# How to copy a cell that has multiple rows without disturbing the rows?

Tags: excel, row

I have a cell A1 that contains several rows:

Anne

John

Grey

But when I type `=A1` into another cell, it returns a combined row:

AnneJohnGrey

I need it to stay in separated rows, so I tried to use `=INDIRECT(A1)`, but it fails. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the cell with `=A1` in it > Press "Format Cells" > Go to the Alignment tab > Check "Wrap Text" under Text Control.

Or you can just select the cell and go to the Home tab > Alignment > Select "Wrap Text".

NOTE: The `INDIRECT` function failed because that allows you to put the address of one cell in another, and get data from the the first cell by referencing the second. More about that [here](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261).

Hope this helps.